# Passing data to partial view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have creating a view page having two partial views login and register.For both ,I created view models and a combined model for both as below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ProjectHub.ViewModels
{
    public class LoginModel
    {
         public string Username { get; set; }
         public string Password { get; set; }
    }
    public class RegisterModel
    {
         public string FullName { get; set; }
         public string Email { get; set; }
         //Some properties as well
    }
    public class LoginOrRegisterModel
    {
         public LoginModel Loginmodel { get; set; }
         public RegisterModel Registermodel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml
     @model ProjectHub.ViewModels.LoginOrRegisterModel

```
 @Html.Partial("_Register", Model.Registermodel) 
 @Html.Partial("_Login",Model.Loginmodel)
```

_Login.cshtml

```
  @model ProjectHub.ViewModels.LoginModel

  @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "account", FormMethod.Post))
  {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="label">@Html.Label("Username")</div>
    <div class="field">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)</div>

    <div class="label">@Html.Label("Password")</div>
    <div class="field">@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)</div>

    <input class="field" id="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
}
```

_Register.cshtml

```
 @model ProjectHub.ViewModels.RegisterModel

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "account", FormMethod.Post))
 {
    <div class="label">@Html.Label("Name")</div>
    <div class="field">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FullName)</div>

    //Some other labels and fields

    <input class="field" id="submit" type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
    @Html.ValidationSummary()   
}

 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Now, when I try to run application.I got error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in Index.cshtml at @Html.Partial("_Register", Model.Registermodel) and @Html.Partial("_Login",Model.Loginmodel).
Please help me.

Comment: I think you need to pass a var model = new LoginOrRegisterModel() to the Index method in the controller.

Comment: Could you show Index controller action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `Model` property is null inside your main view which renders those partials. Make sure that inside the controller action that renders this main view you have properly initialized and passed the `LoginOrRegisterModel` to the view:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    LoginOrRegisterModel model = new LoginOrRegisterModel();
    model.Loginmodel = new LoginModel();
    model.Registermodel = new RegisterModel();
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: ,Sir,this problem is resolved. But, Can you guide me that what should be the return type of the controller corresponding the partial view as I want to redirect the page itself incase it doesn't submit.Now, I get redirected to same page with validation error to other partial view also.Thanks

Comment: please help me in this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040327/validation-not-working-in-partial-view .Thanks